# Select all data except heading, potential empty rows

Tags: vba, excel, selection

I require a macro to select all valid data, copy and paste it into a new sheet and save the sheet. he issue is that there may be no data in a sheet as this will be run for 50+ sheets

I have the below but if there is no data then it selects 1mio+ empty rows.

```
Sub InvoiceBackup()

Sheets("ASM001").Select
Range("A5").Select
Range( _
    ActiveCell.End(xlDown).Offset(0, 14), _
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0)).Select

End Sub
```

Please help?

Comment: As an FYI, A5 is where the header row is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my code I test whether the cell under the header is empy as such

```
Sub InvoiceBackup()
    Dim wksht As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range

    Set wksht = Sheets("ASM001")
    Set rng = wksht.Range("A5")
    If Not IsEmpty(rng.Offset(1, 0)) Then
        Set rng = Range(rng.End(xlDown).Offset(0, 14), rng.Offset(1, 0))
    End If

End Sub
```

I know lots of people who search up from the bottom of the sheet for the last nonempty cell.  My personal opinion on this is that it is too dependant on the version of Excel for me to be comfortable with it.  If another user has a version with a different final row number, that could break your code.

Comment: I've accepted this answer as it is a more robust answer but thanks to both! Both work :)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this in the beginning of the macro:

```
Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Select
If ActiveCell.Row = 5 Then Exit Sub 'because there are no data...
```